# How to convert user input to an int Array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

The closest thing I found to answering this question was converting several string inputs into an array using a for loop.

I just want to take 1 string and convert the first 7 digits into an int array.

This code takes integer values of characters and then tests them against the Unicode values to return true if it is valid or false to reiterate the while loop and ask for input again. When I do this with the Console.Read(); method, and put in an invalid value first, it will say that my code is invalid for 7 more iterations. That means console.Read() has to run 7 more times even if the string has valid input.

```
public static void GetDigits(ref int[] callNumberArray, ref bool valid)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the code you wish to dial.");
        while ( valid == false)
        {//This loop will reiterate the read() function if the code is not valid.
            valid = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
            {
                if (i != 6 && i!= 5 && i != 5 && i != 4 && i != 3 && i != 2 && i != 1 && i != 0)
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
                callNumberArray[i] = Console.Read();// I want to change this

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                if (i != 6 && i != 5 && i != 5 && i != 4 && i != 3 && i != 2 && i != 1 && i != 0)
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
                if (callNumberArray[0] == 53)
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
                if (callNumberArray[i] < 49)
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
                if (callNumberArray[i] > 57 && callNumberArray[i] < 65)
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
                if (callNumberArray[i] > 90 && callNumberArray[i] < 97)
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
                if (callNumberArray[i] > 122)
                {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
            if (valid == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid code. Please re-enter your code.");
            }

        }
```

Comment: What's the point of `if (i != 6 && i!= 5 && i != 5 && i != 4 && i != 3 && i != 2 && i != 1 && i != 0)` lines? How many time have you seen loop variables with values out of loop range?

Comment: I was getting an error in my code that was causing the value of i to become 33, and 38, and I figured this was because the for loop was being reiterated by the while loop and so I used that to control the i variable.

Comment: I guess my answer to your question would be 2 times. :)

Comment: `the value of i to become 33, and 38` it is impossible. Just do not modify `i` out of for statement

Comment: I ran the debug, and stepped through the program and it did that, I promise you.

Comment: It's you directly assigned 33 and 38 to `i`. I promise you

Comment: Nope, you are seeing the whole method, and i is a local variable. I'm not trying to be funny. I'm just here to learn something. I really don't want to argue with you.

Comment: I was being sincere when I posted every post in this thread.

Comment: I think what's happening is that I'm assigning a value to valid inside of each loop and not the main(); variable

Comment: You can delete this condition `if (i != 6 && i != 5 && i != 5 && i != 4 && i != 3 && i != 2 && i != 1 && i != 0)`. It will return true if `i = 7`, but you have already checked it in `for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so After much deliberation I decided to use a separate `Console.Read();` for each element in the array and now it's doing what I want it to do.

```
while ( valid == false)
        {
            valid = true;
            callNumberArray[0] = Console.Read();
            callNumberArray[1] = Console.Read();
            callNumberArray[2] = Console.Read();
            callNumberArray[3] = Console.Read();
            callNumberArray[4] = Console.Read();
            callNumberArray[5] = Console.Read();
            callNumberArray[6] = Console.Read();
//etc etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use Regex, example:

```
MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(Content, Pattern);
var list = matchList.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm using the .net framework. Not sure if I have that library

Comment: Those "libraries" are called shared objects in .NET jargon. The answer uses `System.Linq`, `System.Collections.Generics` and `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. Include them in your code to be able to use this code sample.

Comment: I have no idea how to use this. I'm pretty nooby still. I'm still taking OOP.

Comment: In the upmost bit of your code. There are a number of `using` statements. By default, linq and generic collections are added by the IDE (VS: visual studio), just add the regex. This answer (sadly) uses some advanced topics in c#: Linq, collections (generics), lambda expression, regular expressions.... I highly suggest you take Felix's answer and learn about those topics later on.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to take 1 string and convert the first 7 digits into an int array.

```
string subString = Console.ReadLine().Substring(0,7);
//Check if the whole string is a parsable number
if(int.TryParse(subString) == false) 
{
      Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number..."); 
      return;
} 
//convert it an int[]
int[] values = subString.ToCharArray().Select( value => int.Parse(value.ToString())).ToArray();
```

That's it basically, if you want to do it character by character that's fine, too, but's it's far easier to check for a number using `int.TryParse()` or a regex `[0-9]` (per character) if you're confortable with that.

Comment: Thanks, I will be using that in the future, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the "algorithm" you wrote and I agree with Sergey Berezovskiy that the if's looks weird, anyway this should answer your specific question:

```
public static void GetDigits(ref int[] callNumberArray, ref bool valid)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the code you wish to dial.");
    while ( valid == false)
    {//This loop will reiterate the read() function if the code is not valid.
        valid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
        {
            if (i != 6 && i!= 5 && i != 5 && i != 4 && i != 3 && i != 2 && i != 1 && i != 0)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            callNumberArray[i] = Console.Read();// I want to change this

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if(!valid) break;
            if (i != 6 && i != 5 && i != 5 && i != 4 && i != 3 && i != 2 && i != 1 && i != 0)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            if (callNumberArray[0] == 53)
            {
                valid = false;
            }
            if (callNumberArray[i] < 49)
            {
                valid = false;
            }
            if (callNumberArray[i] > 57 && callNumberArray[i] < 65)
            {
                valid = false;
            }
            if (callNumberArray[i] > 90 && callNumberArray[i] < 97)
            {
                valid = false;
            }
            if (callNumberArray[i] > 122)
            {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        if (valid == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid code. Please re-enter your code.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's hilarious. I don't know why I didn't think of that. haha, lets hope it works.

Comment: ok, good luck, although I really suggest to try and review the whole code, but that's not really related to the question

Answer (score 1):

Here is method which prompts user to input phone number, denies invalid characters and shows current phone number with placeholder for numbers left to input:

```
private static int[] GetPhoneNumber(int phoneLength = 7)
{
    List<int> phoneNumbers = new List<int>();

    while (true)
    {
        EditorFor("Phone", String.Concat(phoneNumbers), phoneLength);

        var key = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) 
            return new int[0]; // return empty array if user cancelled input

        var c = key.KeyChar;
        if (!Char.IsDigit(c))
            continue;

        phoneNumbers.Add(Int32.Parse(c.ToString()));
        if (phoneNumbers.Count == phoneLength)
        {
            EditorFor("Phone", String.Concat(phoneNumbers), phoneLength);
            return phoneNumbers.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Prompt for input:

```
private static void EditorFor(string label, string value, int length)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(new String(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);

    int charactersLeftToInput = length - value.Length;
    string placeholder = new String('*', charactersLeftToInput);

    Console.Write("{0}: {1}{2}", label, value, placeholder);
    Console.CursorLeft -= charactersLeftToInput;
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the code you wish to dial.");
int[] code = GetPhoneNumber(); // if you want default length
```

Console:

[image]

Comment: That's fancy. I don't think I could use that, my teachers would probably think I was cheating. Thank you though.